# How can I make my ERD update with changes without dragging every table to the relational model window individually?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

1. I a table and renamed some columns, but this didn't get reflected in my ERD. I dragged the new versions of my tables to the ERD window that opens, none of the other tables that were supposed to have arrows to it have arrows to it. I can fix it by dragging ALL the other tables to the ERD window individually.
2. I watched a tutorial where a guy just highlights his tables and mass drags them, but this does not work for me. Every time I try to CTR+highlight more than one table and drag them, a window just opens up for one of the tables. Is there a way to mass drag a bunch of tables into the ERD view that isn't stupid?

There must be a way to get around this without dragging every single table in your database into the ERD window every time to change a column name, right?

Comment: point 2 - make sure open object on single click is disabled

Comment: point 1 - use the Synchronize button, i show how that works here https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2013/02/synching-your-oracle-sql-developer-data-model-with-the-database/